# How to doubleclick a listview item with pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I want to use pywinauto to write an auto-click script. I know I can use app.ListView2.Select(4) to select an item. So I tried to use select() or Check(), but it's not working.

How can I doubleclick an item?

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` in pywinauto inherited from `HwndWrapper` which has `DoubleClick()` method, try it. Also make sure you've tried `Select(item)` for `ListView`. (You've mentioned `select()`)